# C# Button to execute ASync Method. (Attempt to Put to Web Api (Phillips Hue))

Tags: c#, api

So i'm just trying make an app, push a button and turn off a light. Simple, right? But i'm a dolt.
So i've never played with Web APIs before (or any api, really). I'm following [This MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) to get a grip on it.  Modifying it to make it work but it doesn't (obviously).
In Button_Click the RunUpdate errors 'MainPage.Runupdate()' is a method, which is not valiud in the given context'

This is probably an easy fix but i'm sure to run into more.  Anyone up to help me out?
Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public class Light
    {
        //public string ID { get; set }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }

    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.100/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    }

    static async Task<Light> GetLightAsync(string path)
    {
        Light light = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            light = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Light>();

        }
        return light;
    }

    static async Task<Light> UpdateLightAsync(Light light)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
            $"api/api/RjplsYoXQvdTl11DOVIo92SKNB7vYRfwZvqCzvDK/lights/1/state/", light.state);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        light = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Light>();
        return light;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunUpdate.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    static async Task RunUpdate()
    {
        Light light = new Light { Name = "Unknown", state = "off" };

        light = await UpdateLightAsync(light);

    }

}
```

Comment: Come on man :) Do not be so hard on yourself calling yourself a dolt:( It looks like you forgot the parenthesis in your Button_Click method→RunUpdate(). However, if I were you  I would not go for a blocking method on UI thread. If you go async, go async all the way

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I got that and a few follow up issues fixed.  Now it just hangs when i push the button. :) I'm kind of the "dive in deep and figure it out" kind of learner.  Still new to a more modern VS.  My most recent work in C# was with Unity so there's that too.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant by go all the way async. You push the button it runs on UI thread. So it hangs until it gets a response from the server.

Comment: AH Gotcha.  New to Async as well. Guess I'll have to figure that out now :) Any reading suggestions? :)  (And thanks 100x)

Comment: A very nice [book ](https://www.amazon.com/Concurrency-Cookbook-Asynchronous-Multithreaded-Programming/dp/1449367569/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=SBPRSED6J515HXWDEVHX)Same person's [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and

Comment: HAHA. I started digging and found that link via Reddit.  I'm checking it out now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, RunUpdate() *is* a method - you forgot parentheses in your RunUpdate call from the Button_Click :)

Comment: HAH.  Wow I'm sad :)   Well now it throws an exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'       UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

Comment: Fixed as well. Didn't have private networks.  Well not it just does nothing which is fun. :) I'll get it eventually and learn along the way.

Comment: That's the attitude :) Glad it helped.